# how to set a pop up height to absolute and make it scroll along

Tags: css

There is this pop up that comes on clicking a link and i need to take a full screen grab of it. My question is how to set the height to maximum and at the same time make it scrollable? I tried height: max-content; but scrolling down only scrolled the background and the pop up remained fixed

Comment: add `overflow:auto` to div with `position:absolute`

Comment: can you give us a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

When you show popup please make the body `overflow:hidden` at this time and add `overflow:auto` to div which is have `position:absolute`. It will solve your issue :)